# Java Runtime error that couldn't load or find a class

Tags: java, netbeans, dll

I'm making a `Java` class that is intended to display `X3D` files, however, when I run it, I get the following run-time error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I'm making the project in Netbeans 8.1 and my current OS is Windows 10. I have had trouble recently with finding out what the bitness was for my version of Netbeans and it's 32 bit. However, when I go into my `natives` sub-folder within the `NetbeansProjects` folder, the `odejava.dll` that's in the `Windows 10` sub-folder was named `odejava64.dll` which leads me to believe its a 64 bit dll. I have got `odejava.dll` in other sub-folders within thte `natives` directory, like `Windows XP` which is why, in the VM Options in the project properties, I've put:  `java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows XP\x86"` and I'm still getting the run-time error. Any help with this would be great.

**EDIT**

My class and project are called `Xj3DTest` and in my VM Options I've added `java Xj3DTest -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\matt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\natives\Windows XP\x86"` and now I have the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Xj3DTest
C:\Users\matt\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you, perhaps, missing a ```public static void main(String[] args)```?

Comment: @JornVernee In my project? I do have `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: which file is having `public static void main(String[] args)` and what file are you trying to run?

Comment: @Blip In my project, there's only the one Java class so it's the main class that has the `public static void main(String[] args)` and I'm trying to run the main class

Comment: The first line **Error: Could not find or load main class java** means that the file you are tying to run does not have the proper `main` method. So, the problem must be with your code.

Comment: @Blip The class has worked before, and I haven't modified it, then yesterday, it came up with this error.

Comment: I'm assuming your main class isn't called `java` cause that is precisely what it appears to be. Somewhere in your vm settings, you will find that you have written `java java ....`. Pick whichever one you like more and all shall be well. :)

Comment: @DebosmitRay I've edited the question now :)